# In PHP string how to replace text to empty space from symbol to symbol

Tags: php, preg-replace

In php I have a problem, in some string I need to remove from `<!` to first `>`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE cXML SYSTEM "http://xml.cxml.org/schemas/cXML/1.2.014/cXML.dtd">
<cXML xml:lang="en-US"
 payloadID="0c30050@supplierorg.com"
 timestamp="2000-01-08T23:00:06-08:00">
    <Header>
```

recommend which is better to use, maybe some standard function or maybe some custom suggestion. 
Thank you for your help.

Comment: look for `preg_replace` and regular expressions

Comment: Instead of writting "hello there" and "nice to meet you", please show precisely how looks your data.

Comment: @Casimir et Hippolyte  I update my qestion

Comment: ok, so the way is to use xml tools to remove the doctype, `preg_replace` isn't the way to go.

Comment: no, because this is cxml format which have dtd rules in doctype tag, but I use jms serializer for deserializer object, but jms don't know how to use deserializer for cxml, only xml accepted and that's why I need remov this row with dtd rules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say something along the lines of

```
$string = "hello there 
<!DOCTYPE cXML SYSTEM "http://xml.cxml.org/schemas/cXML/1.2.014/cXML.dtd">
nice to meet you
and others text";

$string = preg_replace( "/<!.*?>/", "", $string );

echo $string;
```